# Which of “dans”, “à”, “sur” should be used with “j'habite”?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, indications-de-lieu

I would like to write “I live on the campus”. I have written it as

> J'habite dans le campus

But I have found [here](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/to+live+on+campus#vivre+sur+le+campus) “vivre sur le campus” as “live on campus”.
I would like to know if my translation is correct.

Comment: Don't forget the option of no preposition :)

Answer (score 1):

It is much more common to write and say "J'habite sur le campus.". However, you do find "dans le campus" and it is not really incorrect ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sur+le+campus%2Cdans+le+campus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0)).

"Sur" is the préposition generally used  for all the usual constructions ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+dans+le+campus%2C*+sur+le+campus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C3%A9tudiants%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvie%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsitu%C3%A9%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bet%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpolice%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpr%C3%A9sence%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blieu%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsitu%C3%A9e%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binstall%C3%A9s%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C3%A9tudiants%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvie%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsitu%C3%A9%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bet%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpolice%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpr%C3%A9sence%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blieu%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsitu%C3%A9e%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binstall%C3%A9s%20sur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0));

- étudiants sur le campus
- situé sur le campus
- présence sur le campus
- vie sur le campus
- police sur le campus
- installé sur le campus
- que sur le campus

"Au campus" (à le campus) is used but it seems to be essentially limited regionally to Africa ([ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A9tudiants%20au%20campus%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)).

Comment: how to translate correctly: in campus there is a shop? sur le campus il y a un supermarche'

Comment: @AnnaKoroleva In English you should say "On campus there is a shop."; however "shop" is not "supermarché"; "shop" is "magasin" or "boutique"; therefore you have to say something like "Sur le campus il y a un magasin.". ("supermarché" is "supermarket".) As in French you do find "in" also: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+campus%2Con+campus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20campus%3B%2Cc0 but it's not usual.

Comment: @LPH Pour une fois, je ne comprends pas les votes négatifs. Pour moi aussi l'expression largement majoritaire est "*sur le campus*"

Answer (score 0):

"J'habite sur le campus" is just perfect.

"J'habite sur Paris" is awful and incorrect.

"J'habite dans Paris" is fine and means inside the "périphérique".

"Mon logement est situé sur le campus" is fine and "dans le campus" is weird.